# Как выключить стандартный звук прикосновения Touch Sounds?

Tags: android, аудио, touch-event, multi-touch

В своем приложение я использую свои собственные звуки. И они пересекаются с стандартными звуками тача, если они включены в телефоне. Как сделать, что бы в приложение звучали только мои звуки?

Comment: setSoundEffectsEnabled(false) Вот это ваши звуки тоже перекроет?

Comment: @АндроидАндроид Нет, не перекрыло. Спасибо! Помогло!

Comment: Ага, примерно так=) незачто